# Magento2 email template issue

Tags: magento2, email-templates

Magento2 text is not getting converted to lowercase on using the below code in the email template

```
{{ var data.enquiry_type | downcase }}
```

How can I achieve this in Contact Us email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your syntax in

```
<span style="text-transform: lowercase;">{{var data.enquiry_type}}</span>
```

Happy Coding